# Getting environment variables in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, environment-variables

How can I get the value of a custom environment variable in a classic ASP page using VBScript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the ExpandEnvironmentStrings method of the WScript.Shell object to retrieve environment variables.  The following code will assign the value of the PATH environment variable to var myPath:

```
set foo = createobject("WScript.Shell")
myPath = foo.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%PATH%")
```

[More info on the Shell object as MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Edit: Had to change the variable to which the shell object is assigned.

Comment: Very nice, obvious +1! But what about permissions? Doesn't it require any elevated permissions for the IUSR account?

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me, based on [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/12/29/how-to-read-user-and-system-variables-using-vbscript.aspx)

```
Set objWSH =  CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'This actually returns all the User Variables, and you either loop through all, or simply print what you want
Set objUserVariables = objWSH.Environment("USER") 
MsgBox(objUserVariables("TEMP"))

'This returns all the System Variables, and you either loop through all, or simply print what you want
Set objSystemVariables = objWSH.Environment("SYSTEM")
MsgBox(objSystemVariables("PATH"))
```